# Need help building sql query with join and where on many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony

I have two objects that are related by a many to many relationship. These two objects are `Video` and `Category`. A video can have many categories and vice versa. What I want to do, is that if I have a category, to retrieve all the videos that have this category. Also, I have a Section object which has a oneToMany relationship with Video, that is a section contains many videos. What I'm trying to do right now is the following:

```
public function findAllBySectionAndCategory($section, $category) {
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT v FROM OSCMySportBundle:Video v WHERE v.section = :section AND :category IN v.categories'
        )
        ->setParameter('section', $section)
        ->setParameter('category', $category);
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

When I try to test this query, I get the following error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 83: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS, got 'v'
```

It probably means that it is looking for an array but it found a v. I know this is probably a simple question but I can't figure it out.

**Edit 1:**

I was able to modify it the following way so that I can do a JOIN:

```
'SELECT v FROM OSCMySportBundle:Video v JOIN v.categories category WHERE category.id = :category '
```

However, I also need to query the videos based on the section, so I did the following:

```
'SELECT v FROM (SELECT a FROM OSCMySportBundle:Video a WHERE a.section = :section) JOIN v.categories category WHERE category.id = :category '
```

But got the following error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 14 near '(SELECT a FROM': Error: Class '(' is not defined.
```

It looks like I cannot make a subquery ?

Comment: Would the answer from here help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261945/doctrine-2-manytomany-in-clause

Comment: That helped a bit thank you ! however, I couldn't get the whole part of my problem answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Doctrine `IN` function expects a format of `(1, 2, 3, 4, ...)` after the `IN` statement. Unfortunately, it is not meant for column conditionals to prove membership.

However, I believe you're looking for the `MEMBER OF` Doctrine function:

```
public function findAllBySectionAndCategory($section, $category) {
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT v FROM OSCMySportBundle:Video v WHERE v.section = :section AND :category MEMBER OF v.categories'
        )
        ->setParameter('section', $section)
        ->setParameter('category', $category);
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

You can pass a valid Doctrine object or the identifier into `$category` using this functionality.

The example for this is hidden deep in the [Doctrine docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html):

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u.id FROM CmsUser u WHERE :groupId MEMBER OF u.groups');
$query->setParameter('groupId', $group);
$ids = $query->getResult();
```